# How to use slideDrawer on button click?

Tags: android

In my application, I have to use SlidingDrawer on button click but my button is on different layout.Please help with some sample code.

Thanks in advance
Monali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implements this in your Activity. Just set a click listener on the button and activate the sliding drawer.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        slidingDrawer.animateOpen();        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to demonstrate this.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/